# Update product meta_data in Woocommerce REST API

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce

I added a new field using a small plugin script... it works fine in Woocommerce interface and also shows up using the REST API to get a product

Here an excerpt of results using `$woocommerce->get()`

```
'meta_data' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'id' => int 3293
          'key' => string 'kambusa' (length=7)
          'value' => string '123' (length=3)
```

using:

```
$data = [
    'regular_price' => '21.00',
    'meta_data' => [
        ['kambusa' => '456']
    ]
];

print_r($woocommerce->put('products/530', $data));
```

Updates only the price but ignores (without any error) the `meta_data`.

I searched the web all the morning but didn't find any clear solution
(some suggested I have to `register_meta()`, made some tests but nothing changed (the meta data show also before registering))

Following the code used to create the field in the "admin" part of my plugin:

```
$args = array(
    'id'            => $this->textfield_id,
    'label'         => sanitize_text_field( 'Kambusa ID' ),
    'placeholder'   => $placeholder,
    'desc_tip'      => true,
   'description'    => $description,
);
woocommerce_wp_text_input( $args );
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried this to update the meta data for woocommerce REST api wc/v3. You can send the data as an array instead of a JSON string.

```
$data = [
    'meta_data' => [
        [
            'key' => '-- the meta key you need --',
            'value' => '-- the meta value you want --'
        ],
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
$data = [
    'regular_price' => '21.00',
    'meta_data' => [
        ['key' => 'kambusa'],
        ['value' => '456']
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  "name": "Test Product",
  "type": "simple",
  "regular_price": "21.99",
  "description": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.",
  "short_description": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.",
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": 9
    },
    {
      "id": 14
    }
  ],
  "images": [
    {
      "src": "http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_front.jpg"
    },
    {
      "src": "http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_back.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "meta_data": [
    {
        "key": "test_meta1", 
        "value": "test_meta_val1"
    }
  ]
}
```

This how I managed to pass meta_data on POST wp-json/wc/v3/products (Create Product)

Answer (score 1):

**How to filter WooCommerce products by a meta field?**

We’ll start with the most important post type in WooCommerce. Let’s imagine that our products have a custom meta field — Brand. And we want to get all products belonging to a certain brand using WooCommerce REST API. How can we do this?

For example, I want to get all products with the Brand meta field equal to Nike. How can I achieve this using WooCommerce REST API?

As I said earlier, the `rest_{$this->post_type}_query` filter hook doesn’t get triggered when you use the WooCommerce REST API endpoints. Luckily, the WooCommerce developers have added a very similar filter hook —`woocommerce_rest_{$this->post_type}_object_query`.

As you might have guessed, all you need to do is to change `{$this->post_type}` to the post type’s slug you need. Since we want to filter WooCommerce products, we’ll need to use the **`woocommerce_rest_product_object_query`** filter hook. This hook passes two arguments to its handlers: **`$args`** and **`$request`**. We can modify the **WP_Query** arguments using the first argument, and we can access the request parameters using the last one.

I guess you got the idea. Especially, if you’ve already experimented with my previous tutorial. Let’s write some code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_product_object_query', 'filter_products_by_brand_field', 999, 2 );
function filter_products_by_brand_field( $args, $request ) {
    if ( ! isset( $request['brand'] ) ) {
        return $args;
    }
    
    $source_value = sanitize_text_field( $request['brand'] );
    $source_meta_query = array(
        'key' => 'brand',
        'value' => $source_value
    );
    
    if ( isset( $args['meta_query'] ) ) {
        $args['meta_query']['relation'] = 'AND';
        $args['meta_query'][] = $source_meta_query;
    } else {
        $args['meta_query'] = array();
        $args['meta_query'][] = $source_meta_query;
    }
    
    return $args;
}
```

Now, a GET request to the following URL: https://mywebshop.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?brand=Nike, will return an array of products which brand meta field equals to “Nike”. If there are no products matching this requirement, WooCommerce REST API will return an empty array.

**How to use this filter hook with other WooCommerce post types?**

The best part of this hook is that you can use the same logic for all WooCommerce post types. As I said, all you need to do is to pass the slug of the post type you want to filter instead of the `{$this->post_type}`. For example:

Use ***woocommerce_rest_shop_order_object_query*** hook to filter WooCommerce orders

Use ***woocommerce_rest_shop_coupon_object_query*** hook to filter WooCommerce coupons

Use ***woocommerce_rest_product_variation_object_query*** hook to filter WooCommerce variations

You can learn more about the WooCommerce custom post types in the [WooCommerce documentation](https://woocommerce.com/document/installed-taxonomies-post-types/#section-2). In all cases, your hook handlers will receive two arguments: **$args** (an array of the WP_Query arguments defined before) and **$request** (a WP_REST_Request instance which allows you to access a request’s parameters).

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS CODE:

```
$product_id = 123;

update_products_meta($product_id);    

function update_products_meta($product_id)
{

$connection = woo_connection();

$data = [
    'meta_data' => [
        [
            'key' => 'KNK',
            'value' => 'KIDZ N KIDZ'
        ],
    ],
];

$connection = woo_connection();

print_r($connection->put('products/' . $product_id, $data));
}
```

Comment: This code could use some clarification on what `woo_connection()` exactly is